# As400 user inactivity - capturing minutes since user last active (QINACTITV)

Tags: ibm-midrange, jobs

Is it possible to get AS400 (IBM i) to capture minutes since last user activity using QINACTITV system values and read these values back from a scheduled job to write our own custom code? Is this information held in a specific system table?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. No. There is no system table.

You don't need a scheduled job or table to execute your custom code. Create a message queue, set [QINACTMSGQ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarl/rzarltmmq.htm) to point to that message queue. Then a never-ending batch job needs to monitor for CPI1126 messages. If it gets one you can execute your custom code.

The IBM docs contain an [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-system-inactivity-timer-disconnect-or-end-specific-jobs). Alternatively search for "QINACTMSGQ". There are several other examples out there.

Here is the CL example from the IBM page:

Below is a sample CL program which does the following:

- Leaves the console and jobs for user TAA alone.
- Sends a break message to the workstation for users CKOUR and CHANTHA.
- Ends any jobs for workstation P002039.
- Disconnects all other jobs as the default action.

The program can be enhanced to do other actions, including pulling the list of users, workstations, and actions from a file so it would not need to be recompiled each time a change is required.

```
PGM                                                                  
  DCL &THEQUEUE   *CHAR 20         /* QINACTMSGQ SYSTEM VALUE     */
  DCL &INACTLIB   *CHAR 10         /* QUEUE'S LIBRARY             */
  DCL &INACTQUEUE *CHAR 10         /* QUEUE NAME                  */
  DCL &INACTDATA  *CHAR 100        /* RAW MESSAGE DATA            */
  DCL &JOBNAME    *CHAR 10         /* INACTIVE JOB NAME           */
  DCL &USER       *CHAR 10         /* INACTIVE JOB USER           */
  DCL &NUMBER     *CHAR 6          /* INACTIVE JOB NUMBER         */
  DCL &MSGDTALEN  *DEC (5 0)                                        
  DCL &MSGID      *CHAR 7          /* MESSAGE TAKEN FROM THE QUEUE*/

 /*                                                            */    
 /* GET THE NAME OF THE QUEUE TO MONITOR FROM THE SYSTEM VALUE */    
 /*                                                            */    
  RTVSYSVAL  SYSVAL(QINACTMSGQ) RTNVAR(&THEQUEUE)                    
   CHGVAR &INACTQUEUE %SUBSTRING(&THEQUEUE 1  10)                    
  CHGVAR &INACTLIB   %SUBSTRING(&THEQUEUE 11 10)                    

 /*                                                            */    
 /* MAIN LOOP.                                                 */    
 /*                                                            */    
LOOP:                                                                
 /*                                                            */    
 /* WAIT FOR MESSAGE ON THE MESSAGE QUEUE                      */    
 /*                                                            */    
  RCVMSG     MSGQ(&INACTLIB/&INACTQUEUE) WAIT(*MAX) +                
             MSGDTA(&INACTDATA) MSGDTALEN(&MSGDTALEN) +              
             MSGID(&MSGID)                                          
 /*                                                            */    
 /* CHECK TO SEE IF IT IS THE RIGHT MESSAGE, IF NOT, SKIP IT.  */    
  /*                                                            */    
  IF         (&MSGID *NE 'CPI1126') THEN(GOTO SKIP)                  
  CHGVAR &JOBNAME %SUBSTRING(&INACTDATA 1 10)   /* GET JOB NAME */  
  CHGVAR &USER    %SUBSTRING(&INACTDATA 11 10)  /* GET USER NAME*/  
  CHGVAR &NUMBER  %SUBSTRING(&INACTDATA 21 6)   /* GET JOB NUM  */  
  /*                                                             */  
 /* SPECIAL USERS                                               */  
 /*                                                             */  
  IF         (&USER *EQ 'TAA')      THEN(GOTO SKIP) /* leave alone*/
  IF         (&JOBNAME *EQ 'DSP01')  THEN(GOTO SKIP) /* console */  
  IF         (&USER *EQ 'CKOUR')    THEN(GOTO ACTION1)              
  IF         (&USER *EQ 'CHANTHA')  THEN(GOTO ACTION1)              
  IF         (&JOBNAME *EQ 'P002039')  THEN(GOTO ACTION2)          
 /*                                                             */  
 /* DEFAULT ACTION                                              */  
 /*                                                             */  
   DSCJOB     JOB(&NUMBER/&USER/&JOBNAME)  
    MONMSG CPF0000   /* VIRTUAL TERMINALS CANNOT BE DISCONNECTED */  
                     /* SO IGNORE ANY MESSAGES THAT MAY CAUSE    */  
   GOTO SKIP                                                        
 /*                                                             */  
ACTION1:                                                            
    SNDBRKMSG  MSG('Chantha, you left your terminal on AGAIN!') +    
              TOMSGQ(&JOBNAME)                                      
   GOTO SKIP                                                        
 /*                                                             */  
ACTION2:                                                            
   ENDJOB     JOB(&NUMBER/&USER/&JOBNAME)                          
   GOTO SKIP                                                        
 /*                                                             */  
 /* OTHER ACTIONS GO HERE                                       */  
 /*                                                             */  

  SKIP:                                                            
GOTO LOOP     /* GO GET MORE MESSAGES ABOUT OTHER TERMINALS */      

ENDPGM
```